# Renderscript not working android above 5

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm building an android app which uses renderscript and if device android version is higher than 5.. (tested on several devices and observed this but may be the reason is different) it fails, otherwise works as normal

I am new to renderscript so used 
https://github.com/jean80it/RSRTImgProc as a template. 
(this project works but mine fails)

error:

```
11-25 17:37:54.259 19449-19477/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc
E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library
(/data/user/0/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc/cache/librs.filter.so): (null)
11-25 17:37:55.112 19449-19477/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc 
E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library    
(/data/user/0/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc/cache/librs.filter_aqua.so):   
undefined symbol: root.expand
11-25 17:37:55.696 19449-19477/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc   
E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library 
(/data/user/0/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc/cache/librs.filter_comic.so):   
undefined symbol: root.expand
11-25 17:37:56.368 19449-19477/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc   
E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library 
(/data/user/0/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc/cache/librs.filter_neon.so): 
undefined symbol: root.expand
11-25 17:37:57.645 19449-19477/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc   
E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library 
(/data/user/0/com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc/cache/librs.filter_poster.so):   
undefined symbol: root.expand
```

gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stareatit.RSRTImgProc"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        jniDebuggable true
        renderscriptDebuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
} }
```

renderscirpt files are located in rs folder in main

initializing renderscript context as

```
    _renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
```

in the main activity and in another class (in the same package) creating script as:

```
new ScriptC_filter(this.rs);
```

Both tried support library and android renderscript. Result was the same

When minification is enabled, it does not work in any device

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you try doing "adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1" and running the broken case again (close the app and open again)? That would disable any custom GPU driver on the device, and just use the CPU reference implementation. What is the device that is failing?

Comment: I just discovered some interesting points on this code since I asked the questions so there is some changes in the context of the question

Fist: I have 5 differenet renderscript file and thay are randomly failing, givin SIGSEV or SIGBUS erros. I mean, lets say in the first build, everything is ok, than for the second an error is given on one rs context , and for the third, everything fails so an so..

tested on SONY xperia c4 (android 5.1) and works as expected, fails on general mobile android one (android 7), lg g3, g4 ect...

Comment: at this time I do not have any different device to test but when I find one I will try and append results